# Use information from two columns to decide whether to add-Excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Aim: To find the number of employed people for each country.
Problem I face: I was trying to use SUMPRODUCT to get information from Column A and H to calculate the number of employed people for each country. However, from the way I constructed column H, the -1 is annoying and affect my result.
SUMPRODUCT((A2:A201="France")*(H2:H201)),what I wanted to do, but -1 in column H affects the result.

Anyone knows how can I get the correct number(either by other function or change -1 in column H to something else)?

Thank you

Comment: @teylyn hi , do u know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another Boolean to not include the -1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A201="France")*(H2:H201>0)*(H2:H201))
```